# First REST API POST request succeeds but subsequent calls fail with 400 Bad Request

Tags: rest, api, post, http-status-code-400

I am making a POST request to a REST API. This POST call succeeds on the first attempt with a HTTP status 200 and I get the correct result. However, when I make the next and subsequent calls, I get a HTTP 400 Bad Request Error. **Why is it Bad Request when the previous call succeeded ?**
When searching Bing, I found out that this could be related to submitting the same request. If I change some parameter in my payload, the call succeeds.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this? Am I missing something in request headers?

This is my POST Call.

```
POST http://myServer/v1.0/something/queries HTTP/1.1
Host: myServer
Authorization: Bearer some big token
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 72

{
        "field1": {
            "Id": "12345"
        },
        "count": 1
}
```

Comment: Do you have any details on the implementation of your API you could share? Is it based on Java or Python? Are you using a Framework?  Why are you using POST to retrieve data?

Comment: this is based on c#. The api provided only supports POST.

Answer (score 1):

In a lot of APIs, POST data is checked to confirm it is not a duplicate. This is important for some types of business logic such as ensuring there is only one user with some email address for example. In your request, I imagine it may be the `"Id"` field that is causing the `HTTP 400 Bad Request` since there is already an object with that `"Id"` in the system.

Comment: This call basically returns some business data for when id=12345, I would assume this is very basic and simple case. Imagine you have shopping site, the same product (with Id=12345) can be viewed multiple times. (BTW, for simplicity, I have put "id" field in my POST as demonstration purpose).

Comment: Well in that case you should probably use GET, since POST is designated in the REST specification for data creation.

Comment: Unfortunately, GET is not supported for my scenario.. I get error saying "method not supported". Our UI application is not ready and so I am using Fiddler/Postman to make these calls... not sure if this matters.

Comment: Does this happen to be a public api? I can't really speculate on what is happening if it isn't indeed a duplicate.

Comment: It could possibly be a CSRF issue if they are refreshing your token per request.